# how to return variable in another function

Tags: python, function, return

***SOLVED!***

```
def provera():

    komanda = input("\n>> ")
    while komanda not in ("1", "2"):
        print("\nUneli ste pogrešnu komandu.\n")
        unos()
```

How i can return komanda to next function ?

```
def unos():

    provera()

    while komanda in ("1", "2"):
        if komanda == "1":
            unosNam()
        if komanda == "2":
            unosKat()
```

I have very bad problem with function return, if someone may provide me some tut with good explenation of functions in python

Comment: Please, explain again what you want. That phrase "return komanda to next function" ... I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I write a function with arguments?"? Take a look at [4.6 Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: It say me komanda not define and i must return in function unos()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call the function in circles. Just return `komanda` back to the caller in `unos`:

```
def provera():
    while True:
        komanda = input("\n>> ")
        if komanda in ("1", "2"):
            break
        print("\nUneli ste pogrešnu komandu.\n")
    return komanda

def unos():
    while True:
        komanda = provera()
        if komanda == "1":
            unosNam()
        elif komanda == "2":
            unosKat()
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

First, explain CLEARLY what you're asking.
It's difficult to understand.

Second, your code will enter in an infinite loop.
In `provera()` you're calling `unos()`function, and in `unos()` your calling `provera()` ... you'll never end.

You have to explain what you want.

Anyway, what I guess is that you want an argument to your function unos():

```
def unos(komanda):

# provera()  --> Remove this?

while komanda in ("1", "2"):
    if komanda == "1":
        unosNam()
    if komanda == "2":
        unosKat()
```

And then call your function with an argument `unos(komanda)`.
None of these will work though as thery are, you'll have to rewrite your program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with this, but it seems to me that `komanda` is a local variable.

You could try making komanda a global variable, something like this

```
komanda = input("\n>> ")

def provera(x):
    while komanda not in ("1", "2"):
        print("\nUneli ste pogrešnu komandu.\n")
        unos()

def unos():

    provera()

    while komanda in ("1", "2"):
        if komanda == "1":
            unosNam()
        if komanda == "2":
            unosKat()
```

or you could try using `if` and `elif` to do everything in `provera()`

```
if komanda == "1" or komanda == "2"
unosNam()
else:
print("\nUneli ste pogrešnu komandu.\n")
```

Comment: This can help me but also, this two functions are just little part of program